# How to use angularJS $routeProvider and $routeParams

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing

I am building my first angularJS app and I am struggling with getting parameters from my URL into my code.

The URL has a single parameter, subject and all I am trying to do at this stage is display it on the screen...

Javascript:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/setspage/:subject',
    {templateUrl: "setspage.html", 
    controller: "setsController"
  }),
});
  angular.module("app").controller("setsController", function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $scope.selectedSubject = routeParams.subject
 });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="setsController">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Subject : {{selectedSubject}}</h1>
  </div>
  <script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
routeParams.subject
```

to

```
$routeParams.subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller like this

```
angular.module("app").controller("setsController",['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $scope.selectedSubject = $routeParams.subject
 }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried this however it didn't work I'm afraid. I feel like the way I have set it up in the route provider may be wrong. The file setspage.html is the file where I want to be able to access the data via the controller so am I write in putting this as the templateUrl? And is the path write if I am trying to accessing it by "http://localhost:8080/setspage/maths"? do I include the setspage part?